word choice: athletics or athletic meeting
Are the following phrases both okay in American English? How do they differ in meaning, if at all?


athletic meeting




athletics meeting


The Cambridge dictionary has the following phrases:

an athletics team/club/meeting

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/athletics
But then the dictionary is British.

Look for athletic (which is an adjective as used in 'athletic club'), which Cambridge Dictionary shows as: American Dictionary athletic adjective US of or relating to sports: an athletic competition  Athletic can also describe a person who is strong, healthy, and trained or skilled in sports or a particular sport:
Mia is strong, competitive, athletic, and still feminine.

Please supply a full sentence that shows how you wish to use the phrase. Make the example as real as possible  to show the actual context (but fictional).  I have no clear idea what is meant by the phrase alone.

Both of these phrases would be acceptable and synonymous in American English. An American English speaker would probably understand them. However, the most popular term for an athletics meeting in American English is a track meet; similarly, the American English term for the group of sports known in British (and international) English as "athletics" is "track and field", "track-and-field", or simply "track". See https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/track-and-field, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/track-and-field, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/track 4, https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/track "the general name for a particular group of sports...", and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Track_and_field for more information.
Additionally, in American English, "athletics" can mean any sport or exercise or feat of strength, generally, as can the adjective "athletic". So there's a chance that if you described something as an "athletic meeting" (and perhaps even if you described it as an "athletics meeting"), an American English speaker wouldn't know which sports in particular you were referring to. (In fact, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/athletics and https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/athletics don't even mention track-and-field.)
Furthermore, as some other commenters point out below, the term "meeting" could easily be taken by an American English speaker to mean people coming together to do something that is not sports, such as disseminating information, so an "athletics meeting" could be taken to mean a meeting at which athletics would be discussed, instead of a track meet.
"Track meet" is apparently also a fairly common turn of phrase in British English as well. Here are the Ngram charts from Seowjooheng Singapore's answer but with variations on "track meet" added:
American English
British English
P.S.: "athletic" is an adjective and "athletics" is a noun being used as a noun adjunct (being used as an adjective); so, they also technically differ in terms of part-of-speech. That's just to say that you can say "I did athletics" but not "I did athletic". But that's not really relevant to your question.

Thank you. What about "an athletic event" and "an athletics event" in American English?

@Apollyon the same goes for those, including that caveat that they could be interpreted as about any sport in general.
Also, it might be ambiguous to the reader whether you're referring to "event" in the sense of the sports meeting as a whole or "event" in the specialized sports sense of "any of the contests in a program of sports", such as 100 meter freestyle, the second sense of "event" listed here and here. But context usually makes that clear.

Thank you. I just  suspected that  "an athletics event" is not very likely in American English.

I believe your suspicion is correct!

AME here, without this post I would have taken "athletics meeting" to be some event about athletics in some regard (i.e. a conference of the rules commission or the like), not an actual competition.

@Apollyon If you meant "a competitive event," then "meeting" is wrong. I would go farther than this answer and would not say "meet is a term for an athletics meeting," but rather "meet is a term for an athletic competition, and you have confused it with the word 'meeting.'" If this was your meaning, please edit the original question to make that clear; otherwise we're all imagining something like an informational session between coaches and parents.

I concur with Andy Bonner and SoronelHaetir that an AmE speaker could easily take "meeting" to mean a non-sporting event.

@WyattCarpenter I found the following:
Highland Games, originally, athletic meetings  carried out in the Scottish Highlands.
https://www.britannica.com/sports/tossing-the-caber

The two forms athletics meeting and athletic meeting in AmE are about equally common currently.   The singular form of the attributive noun was dominant for many decades before that.
AmE
For information, in BrE, the plural form is more common now after a long period during which the singular form similarly
dominated.
BrE

@Apollyon Note, the same is not true of the similar word "sport." Americans consistently use plural ("I play sports," "turn on the sports channel") while British use singular ("And now in the world of sport," "your only good marks are in sport").
